IFC file extension being blocked from being uploaded across all the browsers
here is a really weird one:
IFC 3d model files need to be uploaded to Fieldwire online application.
Testing it on any Windows 10 or 11, with any browser works without issues. Except...
On one specific location, and only with Windows 10, it is immediately failing.
Windows 11 on the same location works without any issues.
Interesting is, that the failure is seen on a all of the W10 devices and with all of the browsers (Edge, Chrome).
Files can be open without any problems in a regular software (local) that is supporting the file extension.
That makes me think that there is some kind of global policy involved that is blocking the extension from being used in all of the browsers.
Any ideas? And thank you all
Do not see anything out of ordinary in all of the browser
Default application if working as expected
Ran process Monitor (.pml) with two browsers, files are here https://file.io/tT6mzZmSlYXe
